# How do I change the user that the Apache web server runs under in CentOS?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, web-server, permissions

I have one directory called `apps/cache`. When a script writes some files to that directory those files are owned by the `nobody` user. Of course, then those files and folders are not editable by any user.

Is there any way that I can change the user `nobody`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/suexec.html) within Apache to run your scripts as an appropriate user.

Also, consider learning a lot about [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). A *lot*.

Comment: I did that `chmod g+s directory`. Now what that did is make the new folders with group of the cache directory. Then i tried `umask 002 cache` so that i can get default group write permission. But its not doing that

Comment: @user1094163 Do you want to change how apache behaves in the first place, or try and get the situation as it stands now to work? The answer I gave is to make apache and scripts behave better, but not how to get things to work now that the folder and files are under the `nobody` user.

Comment: Thats apache thing is looking bit tough for me. can you solve my current problem as per now

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration (apache) for the directive `User`. This is where you set the user apache starts and operates in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

check these variables in your configuration folder and change accordingly

```
x@x:~$ grep www-data /etc/apache2/ -R
/etc/apache2/envvars:export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
/etc/apache2/envvars:export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Centos setups may have Apache settings under "httpd"

1. make a backup of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
2. edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
3. find the lines starting with `User` and `Group` - create them if they don't exist.

   ```
   User mycustomapacheuser
   Group mycustomapachegroup
   ```